# itemize without pagebreak

Tags: lists, page-breaking

I have the following structure of my lists (commonly):

```
.....

Here is the list:
 * item1
 * item2

....
```

I would like to make my list inseverable (the list with its 'caption' won't be divided by pages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `samepage` environment (which will make it infintely bad to page break, but it may still happen if every other option is similarly bad) or a `minipage` environment (which will mean that it will never break even if it overshoots the bottom of the page)

Comment: Seems samepage is what I was looking for! thanks for help